# Including knockout.js or html from javascript function call

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to learn more about javascript and I've been checking out some code from companies like olark which includes a messaging system on your site.

One thing that I noticed is that when you install their software on your server is that it's just a simple copy/paste of some javascript and then you have a styled window on whatever page it's installed. This has to mean that some HTML/CSS is returned, right?

My question is, how can you go about using javascript and having a form returned or referenced, such as knockout.js? For example, in the most simple sense, say I have the following HTML page. Can I use a `<script>` tag to call to my server which will return a form?

```
//page1.html
<body>
    ...some html here
    <script> function call which will return a knockout.js form/table/whatever along with referencing the file containing the viewmodel</script>
</body>
```

From what I understand anything in a `<script>` tag is not affected by the same origin policy. Does this mean I can potentially use javascript to call for an external knockout.js form?

Answer (score 2):

Using like this 
script type="javascript/text" src="your javascript knockout.js path"
define your path of knockout.js in src in script tag and you can access the function from your knockout.js.

Comment: I understand that, but how about actually returning HTML? I guess what I'm asking is how can I return a textbox and submit button from a js file?

Comment: if you are use simple javascript than you can't return text box, but if using jQuery you may return textbox.

Comment: Is there some kind of form builder that I can use for jQuery?

Comment: It may be available i always use notepad++ for form builder and js. so find it from google.com